# UITableViewCell BackgroundImage for ALL Cells

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm setting all of the `UITableViewCell`'s background image to the same pattern in the below code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectAnAlbumTableViewCellBackground"]] autorelease];
}
```

Which works, except for any empty cells. I'm wondering how can I set the background of ALL `UITableViewCell`'s, not just the ones that have data in them?

Comment: cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectAnAlbumTableViewCellBackground.png"]] autorelease];

Comment: Have you considered using a grouped TableView instead? that way you'll have no "empty cells".

Comment: @MariamN. - Nah, for this particular instance I need the non grouped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the method
`

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Is called only for non empty cells.

So you can increase the number of cells in this method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And when you are in cell with data you add you label or what you want but when you are in empty cell you just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Set that cell image for tableview.

```
  TableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cellimage.png"]];
```

This is my cell image:

[image]

This is my tableview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you Need to Set Background image for `Cell` the Simply use the Use the Following Lines:

```
UIImageView *myImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellImage.png"]];
myImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
[cell.contentView addSubview:myImgView];
```

By using this Code u'll get the image where it Gets the Data The Reason because the only calls when it Gets the Data.

If you want to do so then you have to set the Table Background Color.

Hope This will help.